# How can i split one resource dictionary into two?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a class library which contains quite a large resource dictionary and I think my project's organization could be improved by splitting it down into smaller more specific files e.g one for the control styles one for the colours ect. My problem is that some of the dictionary's use the fields of others (E.g the control styles use the colours).

My question is how can I split one resource dictionary into two and then use one dictionary in another?

Here is what (part of) the full dictionary looks like (not separated)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="backgroundColour" Color="#FF1D1D1D"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="foregroundColour" Color="#FFEAEAEA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="textColour" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="borderColour" Color="#FFF31515"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverBackgroundColour" Color="#E59400"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mouseOverForegroundColour" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mousePressedBackgroundColour" Color="OrangeRed"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="mousePressedForegroundColour" Color="White"/>

    <Style x:Key="DriveButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource backgroundColour}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource foregroundColour}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri Light" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource mouseOverBackgroundColour}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource mouseOverForegroundColour}" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource mousePressedBackgroundColour}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource mousePressedForegroundColour}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DriveImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DriveLabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource foregroundColour}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri Light" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Not knowing how your dictionary looks it's hard to give a definite answer, but have you looked into using `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>`?

Comment: I will look into Merged Dictionaries. I thought that they were meant to be used where you want to use parts of two *separate* dictionaries. I have added a sample of the dictionary i am trying to split.

Comment: Okay never mind, thanks for the help Shaamaan. I think i have it working now. MergedDictionaries being the key...

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer then... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>`?

You can use it to define multiple dictionaries, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Shaamaan I have the desired behavior working. I split the main resource dictionary into smaller files and then created a new file called 'Resources' as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Buttons.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Colours.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

However the only way i could get this to work was to list all of the references to colours as dynamic resources instead of static resources.